# Mysterious issue with the 5.10.7-3 Linux Kernel

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, daemon, real-time

For the last month or so, I've been getting a very weird issue pretty much daily.

I would be using my system like usual, and the screen would just suddenly freeze.

If there's audio playing, the last second or so of it would just start looping non stop.

The Keyboard and mouse would become unresponsive. I can't access a TTY or SysRq.

Shortly after, the Numlock indicator light of the keyboard will shut off.

A minute or two later, the light of my optical mouse will also shut off.

Unplugging the mouse and keyboard and plugging them back in doesn't accomplish anything.

The screen doesn't shut off, probably because it has its own separate power supply.

At this point, the only thing I can do is perform a hard shut down.

The problem doesn't seem related to CPU or memory usage.

Usually, it happens when Firefox is open, though I'm unsure whether that's just because I always have Firefox open.

Curiously enough, rolling back to the latest LTS 5.4.89-1 kernel seems to solve the issue.

I want to dive a little deeper into the problem and understand what exactly it is in the 5.10 kernel that triggers it.

I tried to read the kernel and xorg logs but I couldn't find anything of interest, possibly because I don't know exactly how to read them and isolate the important things.

If it is necessary, I'll try to use every version of the kernel between 5.4 and 5.10 to try to isolate the version with which the problem begins but that'll take some time since it happens almost randomly.

Edit: The issue happened with Kernel 5.9.16-1 as well. When looking at the output of `journalctl` I saw that the last few lines in the output before the computer froze were from `rtkit-daemon` so that makes me suspect that it has some sort of relation to it:

```
Feb 07 11:15:24 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:24 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Successfully made thread 9011 of process 8922 owned by '1000' RT at priority 10.
Feb 07 11:15:32 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 5 threads of 3 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:47 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
Feb 07 11:15:47 glorious-manjaro rtkit-daemon[1131]: Supervising 4 threads of 2 processes of 1 users.
```

Also, this time I did not have firefox open.

I am using:

Operating System: Manjaro Linux with KDE Plasma 5.20.5 (Xorg)

Kernel Version: 5.10.7-3

OS Type: 64-bit

Processors: 4 × Intel® Core™ i5-4590 CPU @ 3.30GHz

Memory: 3.8 GiB of RAM

Graphics Processor: Mesa DRI Intel® HD Graphics 4600

Comment: Not sure it is kernel related, I had similar issue in plain ubuntu, killing `gnome-shell` from a  remote connection would unfreeze desktop. If at home try connecting from another computer or smartphone (termius might be of help).

Comment: @Archemar but that doesn't explain why changing the kernel fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the exact errors as you.
Seems like this is kernel problem which I guess only way is to get newer one or use lts.

Can see from journalctl about the exact cause.

tpm0: [Firmware bug]

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you use a Dell computer?

Comment: Also, grepping for tpm0 doesn't yield anything for me. Grepping for firmware however yields this: `ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored`. I don't think that this is related however, it happens every time the computer boots up.

Comment: I do not think we're having the same issue. Please delete your answer so that people don't think my question is answered.